# Faking abstract methods using exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, abstract-methods

I've been asked this question and am frankly stumped:

*Instead of writing abstract methods we could try to fake them with exceptions, like this:*

```
public int someMethod(int someparameter) {
    throws new RuntimeException("unimplemented");
}
```

What would be the purpose of doing this and can anyone provide an example of code for an abstract method that the above is trying to fake?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What a terrible idea. The compiler would never be able to alert you that you had forgotten to implement one. Nothing would prevent you from instantiating a class with methods that would blow up if you ever called them.

Comment: well that's what I thought.  The question follows (this is an old test question *one that I got wrong* and I still don't understand it.  Anyway the question follows: "Explain in what way the fake serves a similar purpose as the abstract method, but also explain the purpose that it does not serve."

Comment: Was the test question specific to Java?  I can see that this answer might make sense if the question is something like, how can you fake this if you have to write in a language that doesn't have abstract methods.  (Although I don't know of a language that has exceptions but not abstract methods.)

Comment: Yes this was a Java test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of one (possibly) valid use case: You have an abstract class, and a number of other classes throughout your project that extended it.  (Or the abstract class is in an open-source library, so you have no idea what other classes throughout the universe might be extended from it.)  Now, you find that it's useful to add new abstract methods to this class.  But if you add `abstract` methods to the class, this breaks every other class that has already extended it, because those classes need to be changed to contain override for the new methods.  So I can see how, in some cases, it might be considered more feasible to add them as non-abstract methods and have them throw exceptions just in case a *new* class that extends it uses the new methods but forgets to write an overriding method.  It won't be caught at compile-time, but at least it might be caught during testing.

I'm not sure how legitimate this reason is, since it's also possible to define a new abstract class `NewImprovedWhatever` that extends the old one, to contain the new methods.  That may pose its own maintenance challenges, though.  I'm not sure.

I did notice that Java defines an abstract class `java.net.SocketImpl`, that contains two non-abstract methods, `shutdownInput()` and `shutdownOutput()`, whose default implementation is to throw an exception:

```
protected void shutdownInput() throws IOException {
  throw new IOException("Method not implemented!");
}
```

The comments indicate that they were added in 1.3, so perhaps that's the exact reason it was done this way, i.e. not to require modification of other classes that already extended `SocketImpl`.  But I don't know for sure.

In any case, a design like this would surely be really bad code, if the class were designed that way from scratch.  But the nice O-O concepts we learn about in class aren't always so nice in practice when existing code has to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

I have sometimes thrown [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) from a method whose functionality has not yet been implemented. (There is also a [NotImplementedException in Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException.html) which is a subclass of UnsupportedOperationException.) This was always meant as a placeholder and a message to others using the related class or service that the method is not yet complete. Such code never made it to production, however.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of doing this would be to purposefully write **BAD CODE**.
If one wants to confuse its readers and want them to feel the agony of going through their code, then one writes such code.
It also shows lack of designing skills in the code.
A poorly written API will have such code.
Don't do that.

Comment: Probably it is really bad code, but standard Java API provide sometimes such behaviour. See for example "UnsupportedOperationException" on the Collections API Faq: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/collections/designfaq.html#1

Comment: Even `iterator`s `remove()` method throws this `UnsupportedOperationException`, and most data structures in the `Collections API` don't support the `remove()` method of the iterator. Calling `remove()` on their `iterator` will hence throw such exception.