# PHP: what's the reason some people "fake" abstract methods by exclusively throwing an exception in the body?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, abstract

Recently I often see code like the following (this example is taken from Symfony):

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    throw new LogicException('You must override the execute() method in the concrete command class.');
}
```

What is the benefit here over just marking the method as `abstract`?

What's the benefit for the ...

1. ... library author?
2. ... library user?

I already found a similar question for Java ([Faking abstract methods using exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077172/faking-abstract-methods-using-exceptions-in-java)), but it wasn't very helpful as its answers are explicit guessings and opinions.

Comment: [Some ideas from Software Engineering (C#)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128389/use-of-notimplementedexception). Boils down to "should never make it into production" but serves as a red flag during development that something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the comments explain:

```
/**
 * Executes the current command.
 *
 * This method is not abstract because you can use this class
 * as a concrete class. In this case, instead of defining the
 * execute() method, you set the code to execute by passing
 * a Closure to the setCode() method.
 *
 * @return int|null null or 0 if everything went fine, or an error code
 *
 * @throws LogicException When this abstract method is not implemented
 *
 * @see setCode()
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    throw new LogicException('You must override the execute() method in the concrete command class.');
}
```

You could argue with the overall design as it is perhaps a bit hacky but it works well in practice.  Take a look at Command::run to see where the decision to use a closure or execute is made.  Bit of a niche case to say the least.

I know quite a bit of this was discussed in the comments of the other answer but I thought it might help to summarize.  I also did a quick search through the Symfony framework code looking to see where the closure approach was used.  Did not find anything.  The closure support goes all the way back to the original 2.0 release so it might have one of those "seemed a good idea at the time" bits of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A possible use case is optional methods. If you make it abstract then all child classes need to implement it:

```
abstract class Database
{
    abstract public function export();
}

class MySQL extends Database
{
}
```

> Fatal error: Class MySQL contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Database::export)

If you make a regular method then child classes only need to implement the method if they plan to support it.

```
abstract class Database
{
    public function export(){
        throw new \LogicException(__CLASS__ . ' driver does not support ' . __FUNCTION__);
    }
}

class MySQL extends Database
{
}
```

... yet you get a nice error if you attempt to use it:

```
$s = new MySQL();
$s->export();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException': MySQL driver does not support export

Comment: But isn't this a reason to use Interfaces?

Comment: @Foobar `Fatal error: Interface function Database::export() cannot contain body`. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: I meant, if you don't want "to be exportable" just don't implement the `interface Exportable`. So that the "unsupported" method is not there in the first place. `class MySQL extends Database implements Exportable` to support exporting, and without `implements Exportable` when it does not.

Comment: That technique is fine but it doesn't scale because a class can only implement zero or one interfaces. I guess you can create traits instead. However there're tons of pre-PHP/5.4 code out there, what often explains many strange workarounds.

Comment: A class can implement as much interfaces as it wants (ok, technically I assume there's some boundings by how much billions an integer can hold on the arhcitecture). It can only inherit from one class (`extend` can only be used once per class, but `implements` can hold as much as it wants).
And the PHP 5.4 argument doesn't really hold, because I just started seeing this "pseudo-abstract" pattern in the younger times.

Answer (score 0):

only abstract classes can have abstract methods.

You can't create object from abstract classes.

All abstract methods must be implemented in non-abstract classes.

> Constructed Example:

Imagine the following:

```
abstract class Repository {
    public abstract function read();
    public abstract function write($object);
    public abstract function delete($object);
    public function connection() {
        //this is implemented for you by the framework so you don't have to do it every time
    }
```

Now you want to implement a repository for logging user-actions (logged-in, logged-out, ...)

You don't want any of those entries to be deleted and that's when you don't want to implement the `delete` function. But you have to, because your `UserActionRepository` is not abstract, because you actually need instances of it. that's when you throw an exception.

Comment: Why should I instantiate a class that lacks implementation? That's like if it'd be possible to instantiate an interface.

Comment: When you don't need an implementation because you can be sure you don't need the method. I'll try to come up with a usefull/real-world example

Comment: Thanks, I'd really like to see a convincing example. Because to the example-less argument I'd reply "if you don't need a method, don't declare it". Or "if you don't want the class to be extended mark it final". Or "if you must be extended and must have an implemented method mark it abstract".
The situation "class can optionally be extended, but if it's extended it must implement a method" smells like bad architecture because the base class obviosuly does not need this method then -- then why it's in the base class the first place?

Comment: Then just keep the delete method empty in the derived class. In good architecture abstract methods are already called in the base(!) class. What you explain is a use case for interfaces (DeletableInterface, WritableInterface, etc.)

Comment: @Foobar that's not have abstract methods work. You HAVE TO implement them or you'll be thrown a Fatal Error. You're throwing an Exception to ensure the developer that this method should not be called.

Comment: In the Symfony example the execute method is actually called in the base class. Thus you must extend the base class anyways and implement the method anyways.

Comment: Why shouls a base class provide a method that it does not use itself and that does not have to be implemented in child classes? That's dead code then.

Comment: What if you are overwriting the method that is supposed to call the abstract method. then you don't need an implementaion of the abstract-method.

Comment: Sounds like spaghetti code. Obviously I don't need the base classes logic if I overwrite it to not use any of the logic it originally had. Then don't extend the class in the first place, but use an own class.

Comment: No longer discussing this. sorry. I'm really excited to see if someone can convince you that you just have to do that in some cases.

Comment: Thanks anyways. :) You tried to answer the question with examples that use these pseudo-abstract methods only to "solve" other architecural anti-patterns. But I'm looking for an explanation that shows a real use-case that is useful on its own without the need to first violating other pattern.

Comment: @Foobar if you actually look at the doc-block of the method you provided as an example you can see why the author didn't mark the method as abstract.

Comment: `you set the code to execute by passing
     a Closure to the setCode() method.`

Comment: Yes, the author there states that one can instantiate the class -- I can see that by purely seeing that it is not marked as abstract. It still doesn't *explain* anything. That's what I meant. I can instantiate an object of this class but can not use it (because the methods I could call are implicitly calling the pseudo-abstracts anyways).

Comment: Instantaiting a class that already provides a mechanism, don't using this mechanis, instead passing a closure - is this good architecture? I don't think so. I can see how this class is implemented, but I asked for an explanation and benefits without using anti-patterns as a justification.

Comment: of course you can use it! and execute might actually not be called at all!

\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\statusCode::243

Comment: of course that's good archtitecture?! sorry, but who are you to judge this as bad...

Comment: Please don't get personal (on this level we actually both aren't to judge whether this is good or bad design, by the way, so please stay on-topic). A class that is providing a way to circumvent OO design by providing a way to simply get procedural (passing a closure) is not OO. But this gets off topic. It was actually my fault to select an example that provides so much target space to avoid answering the actual generic question (I did not ask to explain this single Symfony example, I used it as an example).

Comment: but this example is a perfect use case! I'm 100% with you that you should avoid throwing exceptions instead of making it abstract. But sometimes that's the only way to solve it.

Comment: But even in this example is it really the the only (or best?) way to solve it? The closure option could have been provided by a derived class implementing `execute` to call the provided closure. Or the default behavior of `execute` could be to call the closure, you could then still override `execute` in a child class.